# SQL database interaction

Tags: php, sql, html, memory-management

I am making a database, which will interact with a SQL table.

What I have achieved so far:

- Add rows to the table.
- Delete rows from the table.
- Search rows from the table.
- Paginate the results.

What I need to achieve:

- A log in prompt when a guest tries to
  access the page.

In fact, I have successfully installed a log in script for it, but it seems to not work properly, here is the error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of
>   25165824 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 77824 bytes) in
>   /home/vol3/byethost12.com/b12_3598660/htdocs/coordbase/database.php on line 238

Now that I do not have permission to allow more memory from my host, I would need a way around this.
I have already tried separating the file into multiple pages, but it seems that it still tried to allocate the same amount of bytes.

Here is the file:

```
<?php
require_once('db.php'); // for database details
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require('../include/session.php');
if (!$session->isMember())
{
    header("../resources.php");
}
else
{
    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; //the $self variable equals this file
    $ipaddress = ("$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]"); //the $ipaddress var equals users IP
    $connect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die('<p class="error">Unable to connect to the database server at this time.</p>');
    mysql_select_db($database,$connect) or die('<p class="error">Unable to connect to the database at this time.</p>');

require('../include/header.php');//Page Header

if($_GET['cmd'] == "delete")
{
            echo "<center><h1>Delete</h1></center>";

            if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
            $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            $queryc = "DELETE FROM coords WHERE id=".$_GET['id'].";";
            $resultc = mysql_unbuffered_query("$queryc") or die("Could not delete the selected base from the database at this time, please try again later.");
            $sqls = "INSERT INTO reports SET ip='$ipaddress', date='$time';";
            //run the query. if it fails, display error
            $report = mysql_unbuffered_query("$sqls") or die("Could not add report to the database, but the base has been deleted successfully.");



            echo "<center>The selected base has been deleted from the database successfully!<br>
                  <a href=http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/coordbase/database.php>Back to Main</a><br><br>
                  <font color=\"red\"><b>YOUR IP HAS BEEN LOGGED. ABUSE OF THIS SYSTEM WILL RESULT IN AN IP BAN!</b></font></center>";

            }
            else
            {


        $queryd = "SELECT * FROM coords WHERE id=".$_GET['id'].";";
        $resultf = mysql_unbuffered_query("$queryd") or die('<p class="error">There was an unexpected error grabbing the base from the database.</p>');

        ?>
        <center>
        <table>
        <table width="83%" border="1">
        <tr>
        <td ><b>Tag</b></td>
        <td ><b>Guild</b></td>
        <td ><b>Player</b></td>
        <td ><b>Base</b></td>
        <td ><b>Location</b></td>
        <td ><b>Econ</b></td>
        <td ><b>Comments</b></td>
        </tr>
<?php
        while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($resultf)) {

                        $id = stripslashes($rowa['id']);
                        $tag = stripslashes($rowa['tag']);
                        $guild = stripslashes($rowa['guild']);
                        $name = stripslashes($rowa['name']);
                        $base = stripslashes($rowa['base']);
                        $location = stripslashes($rowa['location']);
                        $comment = stripslashes($rowa['comment']);
                        $id = stripslashes($rowa['id']);
                        $econ = stripslashes($rowa['econ']);
                        $maxecon = stripslashes($rowa['maxecon']);

                        echo('<tr><center><td>['.$tag.']</td><td>'.$guild.'</td><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$base.'</td><td><a href="http://delta.astroempires.com/map.aspx?loc='.$location.'">'.$location.'</a></td><td>'.$econ.'/'.$maxecon.'</td><td>'.$comment.'</td></center></tr>');
                        }
?>
</table>
</table>
<b>Are you sure you wish to delete the selected base?</b>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="button1" name="button1"onclick="window.location.href='database.php';">
<form action="<?php $self ?>" name="deletefrm" method="post" align="right" valign="bottom" onsubmit="return validate();">
Confirm Delete<input type=checkbox name="confirm"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
</form>
</center>
<br>
<center><font color="red"><b>YOUR IP WILL BE LOGGED. ABUSE OF THIS SYSTEM WILL RESULT IN AN IP BAN!</b></font></center>

<?php
}
}
else
{
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/barbg.jpg) repeat-x top;">
            <center><b><font color="#F3EC84">»Info«</font></b></center>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><!--info content-->
        <td style="background: #222222;">
<?php
   //fetch data
   $data = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['list']));
   $comment = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']));

   $data_lines = explode( "\\r\\n", $data );
   $comment_lines = explode("\\r\\n", $comment);

   for($i=0;$i<count($data_lines);$i++)
   {

      $data_fields = explode( ",", $data_lines[$i]);

      $time = time();
      $queryb = "INSERT INTO coords SET
        tag='{$data_fields[0]}',
        guild='{$data_fields[1]}',
        name='{$data_fields[2]}',
        base='{$data_fields[3]}',
        econ='{$data_fields[5]}',
        maxecon='{$data_fields[6]}',
        location='{$data_fields[4]}',
        comment='{$comment_lines[$i]}',
        ipaddress='$ipaddress' ,
        date='$time';";


      // if it succeeds, display message
      if (mysql_unbuffered_query($queryb))
      {
         echo('<p class="success">Successful posting of ['.$data_fields[3].']!</p>');
      }
      else
      {
         echo('<p class="error">Error could not post ['.$data_fields[3].'] to database!</p>');
      }
   }//end for loop
}//end if $_POST['add'] statement
?>


<?php

if (isset($_GET['cmd']) == "add"){
?>



<!--start inputbox-->
<center><table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/barbg.jpg) repeat-x top;">
                        <center><b><font color="#F3EC84">»Add«</font></b></center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="background: #222222;"><!-- at the bottom of the page, we display our comment form -->
                        <form action="<?php $self ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return valid(this)">
                            <table width="100%" border ="0" valign="top">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        List:
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <textarea name="list" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                        <font color="red"><b>[Post list arranged like so!]</b></font><br>
                                        <br>
                                        E.G:<br>
                                        <br>
                                        (tag),(guild),(player,(base),(coordinates),(econ),(maxecon)<br>
                                        ~TD~,~Team Delta~,DarkLink,Base1,D03:56:21:11,101,101<br>
                                        FARM,Guild896,player 5,Base #3,D69:62:89:10,98,135<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tr>
                                    <td>
                                    Comment:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <font color="red"><b>[Post comments on a new line for each base!]</b></font><br>
                                        E.G "PS 10/10 PR 10/10"<br>
                                            "PR 5/5 DT 10/10"
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="bottom" align="right">
                                        <p>
                                            <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                        <a href="database.php">Back to Main</a>
                    </td>
            </tr>
</table></center>
        <!--end input box-->

<?php
}
else
{
if (isset($_GET['search']) == "do"){
$title = "<center><h1>Results</h1>";


$search = stripslashes($_GET['searchterm']);
$asearch = trim($search);
$bsearch = strip_tags($asearch);
$csearch = mysql_real_escape_string($bsearch);


$types = "types of search";

switch ($_GET['type']){
case 'name':
$types = "name";
break;

case 'tag':
$types = "tag";
break;

case 'guild':
$types = "guild";
break;

default:
$types = "";
echo "<center><b>Please select a search type before continuing! You are being redirected, please wait.<br>
<a href=\"database.php\">Click here</a>, if you do not wish to wait.</b></center>";
header("Refresh: 5; url=http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/coordbase/database.php");
exit;
break;
}


      $querya = "SELECT * FROM coords WHERE `{$types}` LIKE '%{$csearch}%' ORDER BY `{$types}`;";
      $result = mysql_unbuffered_query("$querya") or die("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$querya}");

      if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
         echo $title;
         echo "<b><center>We are sorry to announce that the search term provided: \"{$search}\", yielded no results. <br>"
            ."<hr>"
            ."<a href=\"database.php\">New Search</a></center></b>";
         exit;
      }else {
        echo $title;

?>
<b>for "<?php echo $search;?>".</b>
<hr>

        <table>
        <table width="83%" border="1">
        <tr>
        <td ><b>Tag</b></td>
        <td ><b>Guild</b></td>
        <td ><b>Player</b></td>
        <td ><b>Base</b></td>
        <td ><b>Location</b></td>
        <td ><b>Econ</b></td>
        <td ><b>Comments</b></td>
        <td ><b>Delete</b></td>
        </tr>

<?php


      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                        $id = stripslashes($row['id']);
                        $tag = stripslashes($row['tag']);
                        $guild = stripslashes($row['guild']);
                        $name = stripslashes($row['name']);
                        $base = stripslashes($row['base']);
                        $location = stripslashes($row['location']);
                        $comment = stripslashes($row['comment']);
                        $id = stripslashes($row['id']);
                        $econ = stripslashes($row['econ']);
                        $maxecon = stripslashes($row['maxecon']);

                        echo('<tr><center><td>['.$tag.']</td><td>'.$guild.'</td><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$base.'</td><td><a href="http://delta.astroempires.com/map.aspx?loc='.$location.'">'.$location.'</a></td><td>'.$econ.'/'.$maxecon.'</td><td>'.$comment.'</td><td><a href=database.php?id='.$id.'&cmd=delete>Delete</a></td></center></tr>');
                        }

echo "<a href=\"database.php\">New Search</a>";
?>
</table>
</table>
<?php
   }
    }
else{

// find out how many rows are in the table
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coords";
$result = mysql_unbuffered_query($sql, $connect) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $r[0];

// number of rows to show per page
$rowsperpage = 10;
// find out total pages
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

// get the current page or set a default
if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
   // cast var as int
   $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {
   // default page num
   $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// if current page is greater than total pages...
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
   // set current page to last page
   $currentpage = $totalpages;
} // end if
// if current page is less than first page...
if ($currentpage < 1) {
   // set current page to first page
   $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// the offset of the list, based on current page
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;
?>
</center>



                <!--start inputbox-->
                <center>
                <table width="83%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/barbg.jpg) repeat-x top;">
                        <center><b><font color="#F3EC84">»Search«</font></b></center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="background: #222222;"><!-- at the bottom of the page, we display our comment form -->
                        <form method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="searchForm" onsubmit="return valid(this)">
                            <table border ="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>

                                    <td><center>
                                        Search For: <input type="text" name="searchterm">
                                        Player <input type="radio" name="type" value="name" checked> |
                                        Guild Tag <input type="radio" name="type" value="tag"> |
                                        Guild Name <input type="radio" name="type" value="guild">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="search" value="do">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Search">
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="database.php?cmd=add">Add new bases</a>
                                </tr>
                                    </center>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        </form>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </center>
            <!--end input box-->
        <hr>
        <center>
        <table>
        <table width="83%" border="1">
        <tr>
        <td ><b>Tag</b></td>
        <td ><b>Guild</b></td>
        <td ><b>Player</b></td>
        <td ><b>Base</b></td>
        <td ><b>Location</b></td>
        <td ><b>Econ</b></td>
        <td ><b>Comments</b></td>
        <td ><b>Delete</b></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM coords ORDER BY `tag` ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage;";
    $result = mysql_unbuffered_query("$query") or die('<p class="error">There was an unexpected error grabbing routes from the database.</p>');

        // while we still have rows from the db, display them
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                        $id = stripslashes($row['id']);
                        $tag = stripslashes($row['tag']);
                        $guild = stripslashes($row['guild']);
                        $name = stripslashes($row['name']);
                        $base = stripslashes($row['base']);
                        $location = stripslashes($row['location']);
                        $comment = stripslashes($row['comment']);
                        $id = stripslashes($row['id']);
                        $econ = stripslashes($row['econ']);
                        $maxecon = stripslashes($row['maxecon']);

                        echo('<tr><center><td>['.$tag.']</td><td>'.$guild.'</td><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$base.'</td><td><a href="http://delta.astroempires.com/map.aspx?loc='.$location.'">'.$location.'</a></td><td>'.$econ.'/'.$maxecon.'</td><td>'.$comment.'</td><td><a href=database.php?id='.$id.'&cmd=delete>Delete</a></td></center></tr>');
                        }

?>
</table>
</table>
<?php

/******  build the pagination links ******/
// range of num links to show
$range = 3;

// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($currentpage > 1) {
   // show << link to go back to page 1
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'><<</a> ";
   // get previous page num
   $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
   // show < link to go back to 1 page
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'><</a> ";
} // end if

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
      // if we're on current page...
      if ($x == $currentpage) {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
      // if not current page...
      } else {
         // make it a link
         echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";
      } // end else
   } // end if
} // end for

// if not on last page, show forward and last page links
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
   // get next page
   $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
    // echo forward link for next page
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>></a> ";
   // echo forward link for lastpage
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'>>></a> ";
} // end if
/****** end build pagination links ******/


}//end else of search
}//end else of add
}//end else of delete
?>
</center>
<?php
require('../include/footer.php');//Page footer
}
?>
```

This would be around line 238:

```
<?php
   //fetch data
   $data = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['list']));
   $comment = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']));

   $data_lines = explode( "\\r\\n", $data );
   $comment_lines = explode("\\r\\n", $comment);

   for($i=0;$i<count($data_lines);$i++)
   {

      $data_fields = explode( ",", $data_lines[$i]);

      $time = time();
      $queryb = "INSERT INTO coords SET
        tag='{$data_fields[0]}',
        guild='{$data_fields[1]}',
        name='{$data_fields[2]}',
        base='{$data_fields[3]}',
        econ='{$data_fields[5]}',
        maxecon='{$data_fields[6]}',
        location='{$data_fields[4]}',
        comment='{$comment_lines[$i]}',
        ipaddress='$ipaddress' ,
        date='$time';";


      // if it succeeds, display message
      if (mysql_unbuffered_query($queryb))
      {
         echo('<p class="success">Successful posting of ['.$data_fields[3].']!</p>');
      }
      else
      {
         echo('<p class="error">Error could not post ['.$data_fields[3].'] to database!</p>');
      }
   }//end for loop
}//end if $_POST['add'] statement
?>
```

I have noticed that the memory exceeds the limit when I include session.php to my file.
The problem is that I need that file for my log in prompt to work.

Comment: and what exactly do you expect someone to do with that?

Comment: Hmmmm, it seems that my post is too long, session .php will not fit.

Comment: It is a page where people can add and remove data inside a SQL database. It will also search data in it. It is like a giant database for storing information.

Comment: I would recommend refactoring that into sensible looking code before trying to solve the other problems.

Comment: You need to do some work to narrow down your question.  Show what tests you have done, what do you conclude from them.  Your question as it stands is too broad and doesn't give enough information.  For example, the error message mentions line 208, but I don't think you have posted the code that corresponds to that error.  Learn to ask questions that other people can answer.

Comment: I have made a few corrections about my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check for recursions, this code cannot possibly exhaust memory. Try adding `echo`'s around the code.